# RBAC for kubectl and helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl

Can I create RBAC for kubectl and helm command. Requirement is particular set of user can only run kubectl describe command and other can run apply/create/delete command.

Comment: Yes, you define `Role`/`ClusterRole` objects and bind them to individual users and ServiceAccounts with `RoleBinding`/`ClusterRoleBinding` objects. It is described at length in the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Comment: Helm version 3 is a little friendlier than version 2 in this space: version 2 uses an in-cluster management component (Tiller) which needs [special RBAC setup](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#role-based-access-control), but in version 3 it just runs with the credentials and permissions of the user running the command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you define Role/ClusterRole objects and bind them to individual users and ServiceAccounts with RoleBinding/ClusterRoleBinding objects. It is described at length in the [Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)

When considering helm use v3. Helm version 3 is a little friendlier than version 2 in this space: version 2 uses an in-cluster management component (Tiller) which needs [special RBAC setup](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/using_helm/#role-based-access-control), but in version 3 it just runs with the credentials and permissions of the user running the command.